# Implicit value of if/unless statement in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby, and trying to understand why this works (it does seem to, at least according to ["the Master"](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/148-array_of_fixnum)):

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
    true unless array.find { |item| item.class != Fixnum }
end
```

My concern is where the "false-ness" is coming from when the array contains non-fixnum values.  Am I right to assume there is no implicit "`else false`" in the `unless` statement?  In that case I assume it must be coming from the `nil` value returned by `Enumerable#find`.  Is that correct?

If so, that seems a bit shaky.  Might it be better to return `false` explicitly, like this?

```
array.find { |item| item.class != Fixnum } ? false : true
```

Is there another, better way entirely?  Thanks for helping me wrap my head around this, and for any "best practice" suggestions.

Comment: Why do you consider `nil` to be false shaky?

Comment: The nil is not being returned from array.find() but from the fact that your method has no return value (hence nil) in the case where the array contains a non-Fixnum value.

The array.all() solution below is better because it's more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is returning `nil` not because `find` returns `nil`, but because if your inline conditional does not pass, the method has no explicit return value.  This would be more clear if it were not inline, consider:

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
  unless array.find { |item| item.class != Fixnum }
    return true
  end
  # otherwise don't explicitly return (implicit nil)
end
```

While relying on the falsiness of `nil` will often *work*, it is problematic in that it does not follow the principle of least surprise.  A `?` method *should* return true or false.

But your method has worse problems.  It uses confusing logic (a double negative), and *itself* relies on the falsiness of `nil` and the truthiness of *not* `nil`, to function.  Consider what happens if your method were passed `[false]`.  Oops.

The better way would be something like:

```
array.all? {|n| n.is_a? Fixnum }
```

The reasoning is that this method does exactly what it says, plainly.

Returning a boolean explicitly, while not necessarily wrong, is superfluous and often considered bad practice.  Rather consider the example, which *says*, in ruby speak, *is every one of the values in this array a Fixnum?*.  The result of *that expression* is what the method is after; there's no reason to evaluate it then return `true|false`.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense!  I know ruby methods will return whatever the last executed command was; I guess I never considered what would happen if it were a conditional like that.  Cheers for the help -- the `array#all` method is much nicer all around.

Answer (score 2):

From the find method doc:

```
Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false. If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.
```

Thus, all you need is:

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
    array.find { |item| item.class != Fixnum }
end
```

If anything is found, that will be returned, otherwise nil will be returned, and the method will evaluate do false.

However, as the item return could be an `false` or `nil` (if any item in the list is false or nil) I would recommend that you use the `.any?` method instead.

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
    array.any? { |item| item.class != Fixnum }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at why `true unless condition` works as it does.

I believe `x unless condition` was provided as an esthetic improvement to `x if !condition`, but the two are equivalent (and, in my opinion, it is an improvement).  To get rid of double-negatives, I'll just consider `x if condition`.

One of Ruby's basic tenets is that every statement must return a value (namely, the last expression evaluated).  Therefore, `x if condition` must be evaluated as `if condition then x else y end`.  But what is `y`?  If `y` evaluated as `true` or `false`, `x if condition` would be meaningless when `x` is a boolean expression.  To see why, consider:

```
w = (x == 5 if z == 6)
```

If `w` were true, we could conclude that `x = 5` and `z = 6`, but if `w` were false, we wouldn't know whether `z = 6` and `x != 5`, or `z != 6` and `x = 5` or `x != 5`.  Considering that any value of `y` other than `nil` is evaluated as `true` or `false`, the only reasonable value for `y` is `nil`.  That way, `if w == nil` is be available.  Of course, this is still a problem (in other situations) when `x` could possibly be `nil`.

I would welcome clarification and elaboration.  Perhaps there is also a less convoluted way of making this argument.